# How to print text with borders in Gtk#?

Tags: c#, printing, mono, cairo, gtk#

I need to print table using PrintOperation(). I found how to just print text, but I can't find how to print text with borders (like table). How I can do this? I use Xamarin, Gtk#.

Thanks!